# Flutter Background notification without Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I have a variable called week. Week value changes with Time. I want to show the background local notification according to week.
e.g Current week is 1. so the notification I want is you are in week 1 etc... Even when app is not open

Answer (score 0):

[OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/about): is a free push notification service for mobile apps. this package self-serve customer engagement solution for Push Notifications, Email, SMS & In-App.

```
dependencies:
  onesignal_flutter: ^3.4.1
```